# Best way to start an application efficiently

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-volley

**It's in the question, I would like to know what is the most efficient way to start an Android application that need :**

**1-** xml/json stream to be downloaded with WebServices (text, image url, dataq, ...)

**2-** Data saved in sqlite, and then loaded to be used in the application (data from 1-)

**3-** Data saved in SharedPreference loaded to be used in the application too (some user inputs)

**4-** Images to be downloaded from url (urls from 1-)

What I need is a good way to start an application with all the constraints (data loading from webservice, sqlite insert/update, ...etc) but for the application to be launched the fastest possible and the data to be loaded the must efficiently.

Comment: I couldn't understand this `(should data be loaded at start up ? how ? sqlite after that ? .. etc)` .Could you explain in detail?

Comment: Are these points started without user input (Button click or such)?

Comment: I need advice to rethink my way of starting things up. This is not from user input, it's "from application start-up". The use launch the application then all things must be done to load data, store data, and display them with the most transparency possible for the user. And the fastest possible too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question !
I'll answer with a list of awesome libs.
First you should definively have a look at [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki)
This will really simplify your work. Don't be afraid of perfs on Annotations. it's not reflexion but a compilation step.  It really eases the use of shared preferences.
For http stuff , [spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) is pretty good and well integrated with android annotations. 
I never used xml in WS, But for json mapping , i use Jackson and it's pretty fast and flexible. I think gson does the job well too.

For image loading, UIL is the most efficient and the most mature ( so, it was the case in July when i benchmarked, Picasso and Volley too).

For now i have not found the ORM saint graal, but my advice is "Does you really need a database ?" if you got a doubt backoff. if you need it, ormlite has some perfs problems. In my next project ,I'll give a try  to greenDao.

Definitively use a CursorAdapter for ListView+ SQLite , instead of loading in Listview. But be sure to not access the database intensively at the same time (WS writes).

If you need to pass events like "Hey new data is available in database refresh", don't  make boilerplate interfaces. Use an event bus this is awesome [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Just for the joke, but it's a really good advice. The best way to start an app is definively with paper and pencil.

Comment: This is some awesome advices too. Yep I NEED a database because of the mass data that need to be loaded from JSON WebService. I'll take a look at those library, annotations and Event bus !! In your opinion is there a risk for my application to not be maintainable in the future if I use so much libraries ?

Comment: Yes, for long time projects, you are definively right. But does an app can last for 10 years, without being totally rethinked ? 
I think, on the contrary, that will ease the maintenance for the living time of the app. I tested with and without for maintenance and definitively, it's easier to develop and to maintain/evolve. But I totally understand your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that on pure speed this is the order;
SharedPref - SQLite - xml/json.

Making a network connection is always slower then doing something local on the machine itself. Even if it wouldn't be in perfect conditions, you can not assure perfect mobile internet and server performance. After that, you still have to parse it.

SharedPreferences aren't made for saving whole data structures, just for simple things as small settings which you want to hold on to for a while.

What you want to do with your data is load it from the server once. Preferably without showing loading screens etc. Save this into a the SQLite database. 
On the next start-up, you can (almost) instantly show the data from the database, and update from the webservice in the background to keep up to date.

Comment: I see your point of view. It makes sense. Is Volley a good solution to load data from JSON ? Is UIL a good solution in addition to Volley (for mass image loading)

Comment: I never used Volley, but as far as I know it's a lib provided by Google itself, so it ought to be good :) Universal Image Loader is another lib i never used personally, but a lot of people do so i guess its good. I personally tried Jake Wharton's `Picasso` which works great. http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/picasso-one-dot-oh.html  Simply put the image URLs into your json, save those into the database and let Picasso load them for you when needed. It will automatically cache them etc.

Comment: Nice thanks I'll give it a try. Before  close the question, I still need some advice about SQLITE. For SQLITE + ListView how would you do thing ? Loading data before then pass the list to the Adapter ? Or maybe use a CursorAdapter ? What is in your opinion the best wy to load a listview from SQLITE database ?

Comment: I do not really think that matters, its a matter of preference which you find the most convenient. I guess using the Cursor avoids having some overhead from passing data into another list, but with normal data sets this difference is neglectable. I'm sure Googling it will give you a whole list of pro's and con's on both sides :)